# Pressure Equalization of Two Chambers

Tags: thermodynamics

Suppose there's 2 non-identical chambers, each filled with some gas or liquid. Separately, the chambers are at equal pressure. When combined, will the composite chamber necessarily be at the same pressure?

[image: Diagram]

It would also be intersting to know under what assumptions this holds. Equal temperatures? Equal volumes? Same contents?

Comment: Are the chambers at the same temperature?

Comment: Not necessarily. Is this true for equal temperatures and false otherwise?

Comment: Does the phrase 'combine them' in the question mean that the chambers are connected together by opening a valve in between them? Is it assumed that the gases are allowed to mix and attain an equilibrium?

Comment: They are mixed and attain equilibrium—not necessarily by a valve. I imagined this as two gasses (not necessarily ideal) or a water/steam mixture.

Comment: @s0ggyj0hns0n, if the two gases are at different temperatures, you will have to determine the final temperature of the mixture.  A temperature change will affect the pressure of the final mixture.  If you could be more specific on your problem that would be helpful.  Does this problem deal with ideal gases?  If so, the ideal gas equation would be appropriate.  If liquids are involved, the vapor pressure of the substances would be involved, which would require different calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When connected, the two systems start already in mechanical equilibrium because their pressures are identical. Insufficient information is given to determine whether they start in thermal equilibrium (having the same temperature) or in chemical equilibrium (having the same compositions). Lacking such information, nothing can be said about the immediate future state of the two combined systems. But, what can be said is this: Left undisturbed, the newly combined system will tend to a final state where the pressure, temperature, and chemical potentials of all species are identical throughout.

Systems that start in mechanical and thermal equilibrium will exchange mass (chemical species) to reach chemical equilibrium. The exchange may or may not include heat generation / consumption (enthalpies of mixing). Presumably no chemical reactions happen, but then if they do, the equilibrium thermodynamics of such reactions comes to play.

Systems that start in mechanical and chemical equilibrium will exchange heat to reach thermal equilibrium. The exchange may or may not cause an overall pressure change. Here, account must also be made for whether the system is in a rigid container or not as well as whether the materials are gases, liquids, or solids.

Of course, when the two materials are not the same phase state, that may be a sign that a phase change will happen (or perhaps not). Phase transitions are controlled by the need to balance the final state with the constraints of the entire system, including again the mechanical and thermal equilibrium restrictions.

Comment: Could we explore this further? Breaking it into cases where thermal equilibrium exists/doesn't exist and chemical equilibrium exists/doesn't exist? I wasn't expecting a definite answer but exploring the possibilities has been interesting.

Comment: The expansion to the specific cases is fraught with its own need for specifics and assumptions. You are asking to go deeper down not just one rabbit hole but down multiple rabbit holes, each with their own twists and turns. I will add some thoughts, but the exploration will have to be to you. Take a good flashlight and a hefty supply of food, because the rabbit holes only get more convoluted as you go.